# Separating a complex number into real and imaginary equations

Tags: classical-mechanics, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find motion equations in a rotating frame, using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. I've currently arrive at the function

$$\eta(t)=e^{-i\Omega t}\left[ 
x_0+v_{x,0}t + i(v_{y,0}+\Omega x_0)t
\right]$$

My last step (I believe) is to separate the real and imaginary components to yield a two functions: $x(t)$ and $y(t)$

I know Euler's Identity, $re^{-i\theta}= r\cos\theta - ir\sin\theta=a-ib$.

I'm not sure how to separate into these two desired functions.

Answer (score 0):

I can rewrite Euler's Identity: $$e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta - i \sin\theta \ \Longrightarrow \ e^{-i\Omega t} = \cos{\Omega t}-i\sin{\Omega t}$$

Now I can substitute into $\eta(t)$ and distribute. The real part is the desired $x(t)$ and the imaginary part is the desired $y(t$).